# Unable to get the cell value in rowdeleting event in grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to delete the row in the grid view. For that one i am writing code in the rowdeleting event like below.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
        {
            string UserId;
            SqlTransaction tran;

            using (con = new SqlConnection())
            {

                con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EMASFBAConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
                cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                tran = con.BeginTransaction();
                TableCell cell = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1];
                string username = cell.Text;
                cmd.Transaction = tran;

                cmd.CommandText = "Delete from aspnet_Users where UserName='" + username + "'";
                UserId = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

                if (UserId.Length!=0)
                {
                    //delete user from membership table.
                    errorLabel.Text = "User is ready to delete";

                }
                tran.Commit();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
```

when i debug the cell value is coming as empty. What i did the mistake here?
This grid view has edit and delete button in front of the each row. 
I tried with `Cells[0],Cells[2]` but giving the empty values only. Can any one give me the solution?

Comment: Are you sure you have written code for deleting as in "commandtext" you have write select command?????

Comment: thats ok. i just copied the text from my previous block that it. But here problem is cell value is not coming. It is coming as empty value. See the edited question now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally got the answer. If i try to get the values as Table cells it is not giving proper values. So i tried like this,

```
GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
Label usernamelable = (Label)row.FindControl("lblUserNameValue");
string username = usernamelable.Text;
```

This works fine for me. I am referring the label control inside the gridview and getting the value.

Comment: You got it before I wrote the same answer, if you are using ItemTemplate Rows then better to get the value by FindControl() method

Answer (score 3):

hi define datakeys in the gridview and use this method

```
   string UserID = GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
```

and then based on this ID delete the row.

```
   cmd.CommandText = "Delete from aspnet_Users where UserID=" + UserID;
```

after that call your databind method to bind the gridview with updated records

for datakeynames please use this

```
      <asp:gridview datakeynames="UserID"
      runat="server">
```

Comment: its really simple you can set it in html as :

 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" DataKeyNames="Id" runat="server">
    </asp:GridView>

Answer (score 1):

try the following code:

```
var empId = Convert.ToInt32(this.gvDetails.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["EmpId"].ToString());
```

Comment: To me this is the proper way to get the value of a specific key.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
protected void NPNGridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   GridViewRow gvr = NPNGridView1.SelectedRow;
   TextBox1.Text = gvr.Cells[1].Text;         
}
```

it's working, before u run the solution, please once test this Cells[1] indexes,